# read file from url path and display in chart format

Tags: coldfusion

i working on one project. i want to read file which path from url,this file containing xml data i have to show this data in chart format.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your steps may be these:

1. Validate the URL data (StructKeyExists + FileExists + isFile).
2. Read and parse XML file, you can do this with [XmlParse](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_t-z_23.html).
3. Convert XML object into the query (see [query functions](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_t-z_23.html)).
4. Render the data using great [charting tags](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/graphing_01.html).

If you want more detailed help -- please expand your question, to make it more specific.